# Show the child nodes in Infragistics GridView

Tags: asp.net, .net, infragistics

I have implemented a hirearcial ultrawebgrid. It works as expected. 
It will work like, There is a "+" icon in top row and when user clicks on the "+" it will show the child rows. All these things are working fine.

When the grid is rendered it hiding th child nodes, it will opens only when the user clicks on "+". I want the grid to show all the childnodes by default. How can i obtain that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand programmatically all nodes in a UltraWebGrid you could use this line

```
Me.UltraWebGrid1.ExpandAll()
```

Comment: is there any property , so that i need to  modify only the aspx page ?

Comment: To my knowledge, no. I have searched for this before giving my answer and I have found anything.

Comment: The method needs to be used, there isn't a property that does this automatically.

Comment: @alhalama, thanks for your confirm. I was waiting your input :-)